# How can I keep track of the number of cards in my collection while drafting?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

When drafting on Magic Arena, I know that to optimally build up my collection, I should be aiming to draft no more than 4 of each rare/mythic as there's no duplicate protection.

In order to do this, I've just been entering in each card I draft into a spreadsheet that lists all the rares/mythic so I know once I hit 4 copies.

Is there any easier way to track this in game or with an external tracking program?

Answer (score 3):

Holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while drafting will overlay the number of copies in your collection on each card with a message like `2/4`. There doesn't seem to be a button on the screen to press for touchscreen users, though.